# Mail app window will not open

Tags: window, osx-yosemite, email-client

I select Mail from dock or applications,  the dot shows beneath the mail icon, but the Mail window does not open.  I have to right-click the icon and select new window.  Anyway to get this back working normal?

OS/Compunter: 10.10.3 Yosemite (Mid 2012 MacBook Air)

Comment: See [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154594/mail-app-wont-start-osx-10-10-yosemite) at Ask Different. The suggestion is to add the email account via System Preferences -> Internet Accounts first.

Comment: How about unpin it from dock, launch from applications folder then pin it back?

Comment: Same problem... Nope does not work. Any luck with this?